# ACE/TAO How to configurated transport for simple application chat

Tags: corba, ace, tao, ace-tao

I am learning ACE/TAO library(C++ framework) and trying to set up a sample app in ACE_wrappers\TAO\examples\Simple\chat directory via shmiop(shared memory) transport, how to do it?

I am builded simple applications chat on tcp/ip transport and writed chat.conf

```
dynamic SHMIOP_Factory Service_Object *TAO_Strategies:_make_TAO_SHMIOP_Protocol_Factory () ""

dynamic Advanced_Resource_Factory Service_Object *
  TAO_Strategies:_make_TAO_Advanced_Resource_Factory ()
    "-ORBProtocolFactory SHMIOP_Factory "".
```

Run server with keys `server -ORBEndpoint shmiop://12345 -ORBSvcconf chat.conf`. Run client with keys `client -ORBEndpoint shmiop://12345 -ORBSvcconf chat.conf`, client not work `CORBA::Exception name = "IDL:omg.org/CORBA/TRANSIENT:1.0`

Debug show:

```
Exception thrown at 0x75E1EAE2 in server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CORBA::TRANSIENT at memory location 0x00CFC294.
Exception thrown at 0x75E1EAE2 in server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Exception thrown at 0x75E1EAE2 in client.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CORBA::TRANSIENT at memory location 0x03A2E374.
Exception thrown at 0x75E1EAE2 in client.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
```